# Can't get the second View to show. Probably hidden under first view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout which consists of a TableLayout and a WebView. Only one of which should be shown. I've set all Views to visibility:gone. So, if the TableView is atop, I can't see the WebView and vice versa.

My Layout file looks like this:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nest1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="3"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
                    android:background="@color/design_default_color_background"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:text="Linie"
                        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:text="Endstation"
                        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:text="Abfahrt"
                        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary" />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nest2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If I switch Tableview with Webview, then I can see the webview, but not the Tableview. Even thought all are set to GONE and I set the one view I want to see to VISIBLE.

I guess the second view is at the bottom of the first view and is there but "hidden".

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Edit:
Code to enable/disable view looks like this

```
        NestedScrollView v1 = findViewById(R.id.nest1);
        NestedScrollView v2 = findViewById(R.id.nest2);
        TableLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.tableLayout2);
        TableRow row = findViewById(R.id.tableRow0);
        WebView wv2 = findViewById(R.id.webView2);

            v1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            v2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            row.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            wv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use match_parent size for WebView and TableView, so one of views displayed on whole screen and another one doesn't have enough space for inflating. Change height and width for one of views to wrap_content. It maybe helps you.

Comment: I already tried that. Unfortunately it's not working. Same behavior.

Comment: Can you show me how you change visibility from code?

Comment: I edited the first post. I also noticed that when using gone none of the views can be seen. I suspect I need to add Layout Parameters?

Comment: Everything is looking good, try to invalidate cashes and restart your studio. Maybe it helps

Comment: LayoutParams is using for adding views from code, your situation is another. Try to add boolean flag which helps you to monitor which view need to display or change your layout.

Comment: I agree. Nothing to do with LayoutParams.

Comment: I agree. Nothing to do with LayoutParams.

Let me describe what I did to test:

Nestview 1 -> Tablelayout
Nestview 2 -> WebView

boolean nest1 = true;

Nestview 1 get shown  (ok)
Nestview 2 is hidden  (ok)

boolean nest1 = false
Nestview 1 is hidden (ok)
Nestview 2 is not be seen


I changed the Layout order in XML
Nestview 1 -> WebView
Nestview 2 -> Tablelayout

boolean nest1 = true
Nestview 1 get shown  (ok)
Nestview 2 is hidden  (ok)

boolean nest1 = false
Nestview 1 is hidden (ok)
Nestview 2 is not to be seen

Do I have to change the position from Nestview 2?

Comment: You can try it. If table doesn't connect with WebView, you can use fragments with independent layouts. It will be much easier to control the visibility of elements

Comment: I ended up using two layouts. It was indeed easier.